# How to view existing LDAP users in IBM Tivoli Directory Structure Web Administration Tool

Tags: ldap, websphere, tivoli

I have IBM Tivoli Directory Structure (LDAP) v 6.3.1 installed on one of my servers. I have configured IBM Tivoli Directory Structure to view all the existing users and groups that I have configured. I checked one of the IBM articles in which it was told to configure a realm prior to checking users and groups. But there was no section through which a realm can be configured. Can anyone kindly suggest how can we create realm and view users ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Liberty? If so, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ldap.html. Otherwise follow this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_5.0.1/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_instl_config_ldap_on_was.html. If you are on traditional websphere, you are likely using the default realm. You can look at your configuration under [profile_home]/config/cells/[cell]/wim/config/wimconfig.xml

Comment: Hi Ryan ..... The file 'winconfig.xml' contains references of 'defaultWIMFileBasedRealm'. I also checked from the IBM Console in Security ---> Global Security ---> Federated repositories. It contained realm name as 'defaultWIMFileBasedRealm'. So in that case do I need to create a fresh realm or not ? Because in IBM Tivoli Web Administration tool it is is showing message to first configure realm and then view users and groups.

Comment: Also it is not Liberty.

Comment: You don't need to create a realm. Try going to manage users -> users. Do your users show up in the admin console? If not, go back to global security -> federated repositories -> repository. Check your user and group filters. Check your objectclass mappings, eg. PersonAccount using inetOrgPerson instead of PosixAccount (or whatever you need)

Comment: Hi Ryan ..... Thanks for your answer . I am able to view my users and groups in the admin console i.e the ibm console. But I want to view it in the IBM tivoli Directory structure web administration tool. I am able to view the users I created in the 'Manage Directories' section instead of the 'Manage Users' section. Whenever I am clicking 'Manage Users' there, it is asking me to create a realm.